# preventing addition of system Python path to virtualenv easy-install.pth by python setup.py develop

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools, setup.py, distribute

When I attempt to add a Python package under development with `distribute` to a `virtualenv` via `python setup.py develop`, the system Python path (`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` on my Ubuntu 13.04 system) is automatically added to the virtualenv's `easy-install.pth` file. This seems to occur when the package under development has a dependency that is available in the system Python path even if it is also installed and active in the virtualenv. Is there some way to prevent `python setup.py develop` from adding the system Python path to `easy-install.pth` when a required package already is installed in the virtualenv? I want to avoid adding the system Python path to `easy-install.pth` because it confuses the `distribute` entry point mechanism of Python packages that are available both in the virtualenv and in the system Python path (e.g., ipython).

Comment: did you run `activate` in your virtualenv?

Comment: Yes - I am running the python executable installed in the virtualenv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
python setup.py develop
```

That ^ python  that you are using to run setup.py is not necessarily associated with the virtual environment.  You need to ensure that you are running the virtualenv's version of python by navigating directly to python.exe in your virtual environment  and using that to run setup.py.

Alternatively you can just call `activate.bat` in your scripts folder and it will do it all for you, ensuring that nothing outside of the virtual environment is used.

**edit** if you are certain that you are using the virtualenv's `python.exe` please ensure that when you created the virtual env you used the --no-site-packages flag

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages myEnv
```

**edit2** the --no-site-packages seems to have been OP's problem

Comment: I confirmed that I am running the virtualenv's own python executable.

Comment: @lebedov did you use the --no-site-packages flag?

Comment: Thanks - that was the problem.